# Getting error code 1054 when running sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to get the user with oldest account created using this:

```
SELECT a.ID
     , a.username 
  FROM users a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(date_created) 
        FROM other_info
     ) b 
    ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

It's returning the following; `Error Code: 1054.

Unknown column 'b.ID' in 'on clause'`

I've looked though the [mysql-error-1054] tag and haven't been able to find a solution, I'm not even sure which part of the query is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Your subquery returns no column named ID.

Comment: In the subquery, you are only getting one date value, so you don't have an ID column

Comment: Your query should be SELECT a.ID, a.username FROM users a INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date_created) FROM other_info group by id) b ON a.ID = b.ID;

Comment: Presumably other_info is simply an annexe table; in other words, there's a one-to-one correlation between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the user with the first (oldest) date_created:

```
SELECT u.ID, a.username, b.date_created
FROM users a
INNER JOIN other_info b
ORDER BY b.date_created
LIMIT 1
```

BTW, instead of `a`, `b` etc, I'd rather chose table aliases that make sense, e.g. `u` for `users`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.ID
, a.username
, MAX(date_created)
FROM users a
INNER JOIN other_info b
ON a.ID = b.ID;

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
SELECT a.ID, a.username 
FROM users a INNER JOIN 
(SELECT top 1 id,date_created FROM other_info order by date_created desc) b 
ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

Comment: `top 1`is for SQL Server. OP is using MySQL.